# PySide metro style mousepressevent

Tags: python, microsoft-metro, mouseevent, pyside, qrect

I am trying to have a python desktop application with metro (Windows 8) style, so a table of rectangles which can be clicked to do something.

I generate the table of rectangles (MyIcon) like this:

```
for sub_rectx in xrange(4):
    for sub_recty in xrange(3):
        tmp = MyIcon(sub_rectx*322, sub_recty*192, 300, 170, sub_recty+3*sub_rectx + 1, parent=parent)
```

and I have my class, which basically is a rectangle with an id:

```
class MyIcon(MyPanel):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, ide, parent=None):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, parent)
        self.ide = ide

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        print self.ide
```

This code works fine the first time I click on a rectangle, printing the correct id, and changing the colour of the correct rectangle, however the next times I click on any rectangle it's always printing the id of the first rectangle I clicked and the colour is not changed (I assume because it's painting again the same rectangle as well).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

1) when you call super(..) you have to pass the current class as first parameter (`MyIcon` and not `MyPanel`). Pass the proper parameters, and don't call the **init** function of QGraphicsRectItem there (your parent class probably does it).

2) In your mouse event handler, you should call the super function too:

`super(MyIcon, self).mousePressEvent(event)`

This should solve the issue.